# Initialize with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() 
        {
var element1 = getElementById('#SelectTable1');
element1.style.background = element1.options[element1.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
```

I have a dropdown box which contain colorthat I want to initialise its value as its background. The select does work. I just can't make it to be initialized with the background that has the color of selectedindex.value.

The html code for the select is below:

```
<select class="tableselect" id="SelectTable1" onchange="this.style.background=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="#4eb96e">ΟΛΟΚΛΗΡΩΘΗΚΕ</option>
        <option value="#e57d24">ΑΝΑΜΟΝΗ</option>
        <option value="#efc319">ΕΠΙΔΙΟΡΘΩΝΕΤΑΙ</option>
        <option value="#e64c3b" selected>ΑΠΟΡΡΙΦΘΗΚΕ</option>
    </select>
```

The onchange does work. I wish I could find a way to initialize my select's background with its value. Tried css.background and does not work. Only style.background does..

Comment: Why are you using jQuery _and_ vanilla DOM selectors?

Comment: `getElementById('#SelectTable1')` - get rid of the hash here.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is a syntax error, you didn't close the DOM ready handler properly.

Second problem is you use `#` with `document.getElementById()`, which it does not require.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BDAKW/)**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var element1 = document.getElementById('SelectTable1'); // no #
    element1.style.background = element1.options[element1.selectedIndex].value;
}); // <-- close properly
```

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well make full use of it:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var element1 = $('#SelectTable1');
    element1.css('background', element1.val());
});
```

Comment: Check this fiddle it's working http://jsfiddle.net/8pajp/ you must be doing something different in your code...

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here][1]Use jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var selElem = $('#selColor');
        var bgColor = selElem.val();
        selElem.css("background-color", bgColor);
     });


   http://jsfiddle.net/HavgB/
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it didnt work. Also I think there is a comma instead of a :

Comment: OK this one does work on jsfiddle but I can't understand why it doesn't on my page. I used your code and replaced mine. Still doesn't work. :((